# Extract year contents from html code and save them as dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a section of html source code named `li` as follows:

```
[<li>Project construction cycle</li>,
     <li>
                             Start date: 2019...
                             Completion date: 2021... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
     </li>,
     <li>Preliminary preparation progress</li>,
     <li>
                             The project has been completed by... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
     </li>,
     <li>Progress in design work</li>,
     <li>
                             The project design has... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
     </li>,
     <li>Procurement of equipment</li>,
     <li>
                             The project equipment... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
     </li>,
     <li>Project construction progress</li>,
     <li>
                             The project is in... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
     </li>]
```

How could we extract `Start date` and `Completion date` and convert them to a dataframe?

PS: I convert it to dataframe because I need to concatenate it with other columns.

The expected result:

```
   Start date  Completion date
0        2019             2021
```

Thanks.

**Updates:**

```
li = str(li)
s = re.compile('Start date：[0-9]{4}').findall(li)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split('：')for x in s ]).set_index(0).T

e = re.compile('Completion date：[0-9]{4}').findall(li)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split('：')for x in e ]).set_index(0).T

# df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
```

**New update:**

```
rmktxt2 = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"mse_new"}).find("ul", attrs={"class":"rmktxt2"})
li = rmktxt2.find_all("li")
li = str(li)
li = " ".join(li.split())
regex = r"(Start date：\d{4}|Completion date：\d{4})"
data = re.findall(regex, li)
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('：')for x in data]).set_index(0).T
print(df)
```

Out:

```
0  Start date  Completion date
1  2019  2021
```

Now how can I set index `0` starting from row of `2019  2021`?

**Updates:**

```
regex = r"Start date：(\d{4}).*Completion date：(\d{4})"
data = re.findall(regex, li)[0]
out['Start date'] = data[0]
out['Completion date'] = data[1]
df = pd.DataFrame([out])
```

Out:

```
   Start date  Completion date
0        2019             2021
```

Comment: I have used to code in the updates part, it works, but not concise, maybe you could help to improve it.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yeah could you post your answer pls?

Comment: I’ll try and let u know, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
(Start date: \d{4}|Completion date: \d{4})
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(Start date: \d{4})`** - Represents first capturing group matching `Start date:`  literally along with digits appearing exactly 4 times.
- **`|`** - Represents alternation.
- **`Completion date: \d{4})`** - Matches `Completion date:`  literally along with digits appearing exactly 4 times.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/BQxJZT/3)

#### Code Demo

Comment: It works for extract the interested elements: `[('Start date: 2019', ''), ('', 'Completion date: 2021')]`, but also i need to convert it to dataframe for the purpose of concatenation with other elements.

Comment: A little bit different, we need to convert `[('Start date: 2019', ''), ('', 'Completion date: 2021')]` to `['Start date: 2019', 'Completion date: 2021']`, right?

Comment: Could you please take a look about `new updates` in my question?

Comment: It's simple use `header = 1`. as `pd.DataFrame()` argument.

Comment: You mean `pd.DataFrame([x.split('：')for x in data], header = 1).set_index(0).T`? It raises an error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'`.

Comment: It raises an error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'`

Comment: See why don't you try to add the header manually? Is it a problem with that.

Comment: I edit based on your solution and get expected result. Please check my update in OP.